# MVC Client Is Not Redirecting To IdentityServer4 Login UI

Tags: identityserver4

I'm working my way through the IdentityServer4 quickstarts and am having problems getting the Implicit quickstart to work.  I've started everything from scratch and followed through the instructions with no problems (clientcredentials, resourceownerpassword, etc) until I try to get the MVC client to access a controller method with the Authorize attribute using the Implicit flow.  All my code appears to match that in the GitHub samples (with appropriate port changes and such), yet when the MVC client accesses the controller, it receives a 401 error which is appropriate....but it does not display the quickstart MVC UI (installed into the IdentityServer project using the provided powerscript file) so that I can log in.  It seems like I'm missing something.  I've provided the logging, output, and what I understand to be the relevant code below.  How do I connect a failed MVC attempt to the login UI?

I'd appreciate any insight you can provide!

Port 50488 is the identityserver .net core app
Port 61022 is the MVC client app

Logging Console for IdentityServer during MVC client attempt:
[IdentityServer4 Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv8xA.png)

Visual Studio Output Window:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:61022/Home/Contact
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information:
>   Authorization failed for user: (null).
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Warning:
>   Authorization failed for the request at filter
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing
>   ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
>
> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\keith.hurley.nuget\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\keith.hurley.nuget\packages\System.Globalization.Extensions\4.3.0\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\keith.hurley.nuget\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions\1.1.0\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\keith.hurley.nuget\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions\1.1.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\keith.hurley.nuget\packages\System.Security.Principal\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.Security.Principal.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\keith.hurley.nuget\packages\System.Text.RegularExpressions\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.6\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\keith.hurley.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'.
>   Module was built without symbols.
>
> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\keith.hurley.nuget\packages\System.IO.Compression\4.3.0\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.3\System.IO.Compression.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\keith.hurley.nuget\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates\4.3.0\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.6\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\keith.hurley.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'.
>   Module was built without symbols.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMiddleware:Information:
>   AuthenticationScheme: oidc was challenged.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   finished in 1121.3286ms 401

IdentityServer Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace Ident4
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                .AddInMemoryScopes(Config.GetScopes())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddInMemoryUsers(Config.GetUsers());

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

            //app.Run(async (context) =>
            //{
            //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            //});
        }
    }
}
```

IdentityServer client

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId="mvc",
                    ClientName="MVC Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes=GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    RedirectUris= {"http://localhost:61022/signin-oidc"},
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:61022" },
                    AllowedScopes=
                    {
                        StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
                        StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
                        "api1"
                    }
                }
```

MVC_client Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace MVC_client
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "cookies"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
                SignInScheme = "cookies",
                Authority = "http://localhost:50488/",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                ClientId = "mvc",
                SaveTokens = true
            });


            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: running this sample doesn't work either? https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication

Comment: The sample does...but when I follow the quickstart from scratch...the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same problem. For me it was nuget package issue.

During bootstrapping the aspnet core project it adds packages "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" with version "1.1.0".

Changing packages version back to "1.0.*" works for me.